# Other sites copying content and making it nonsensical

Tags: duplicate-content

I have found content from my site being hosted on other sites. Some of these sites convert the content into gibberish, which I suspect is accomplished using artificial intelligence. I presume there is kind of financial motivation, but what is going exactly? How does the scheme work? Is it negative SEO from some competitor?

Comment: do you have some examples? Depending on how "gibberisch" it is, they might just automatically copy yours and other content but did not build a specific scraper for your page and are stumbling over the format of your content. Here is an anti scraping library you might want to take a look at in order to prevent ppl copying your content. https://github.com/terrylinooo/shieldon   as well as an explanation on how to combat https://github.com/JonasCz/How-To-Prevent-Scraping

Comment: The gibberish looks like a composite of sentences. Some of the sentence are from my site and some are from related sites. Other sentences are taken from content that was created by competitors who have similar products. Everything is mixed up and makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not an expert in any means about computer-driven (likely malicious) websites such as these, I think I can answer the question about the financial motivation.

**There are a couple things the malicious people might want:**

- Money. If they get ad revenue or monetary value out of their website somehow, they can do it. If it is A.I driven, as you believe, they are basically pirating your content.
- Popularity. If the domain gets popular, they can actually get some use out of it. If you create content that attracts search engines, they will want the SEO.

**Why it's bad for you:**

- If you are a starting website, it's very possible that they might actually outcompete you and drive you to the bottom. If you are a larger website that's been around a little bit, you are probably fine (or at least better off and at less risk)
- It can direct ad revenue from you to them.